# Error parsing timestamp

Tags: java, android, datetime, google-docs

So I'm modifying one of the opensource Google I/O opensource applications (2010) and I'm getting the following error when trying to sync the app with using custom Google spreadsheet, same headings different data (appears to sync fine with the default Google spreadsheet)

"Sync error: Problem parsing timestamp: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "null 2010 10:45am -0700"

This is the Java Code that's throwing the error

```
     private static long parseTime(String date, String time) throws HandlerException {
    final String composed = String.format("%s 2010 %s -0700", date, time);
    try {
        return sTimeFormat.parse(composed).getTime();
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        throw new HandlerException("Problem parsing timestamp", e);
    }
    }
```

Here's links to the information (Atom) which it is trying to parse:
My Data
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/0AmvmSNjQXtJFdE1lTlFxVXZCLUN0OFpqa3oyM2d4bEE/public/basic

Google Data
http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/twd6syM493oFqIFWeIm8qGw/public/basic"

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check the parameter date you pass into this method. It seems to be `null`, which obviously is not a valid date.

Comment: This was my first thought also, the application reads in a column which has dates in it, but none of these are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Because @henrik has already posted what your actual current problem is, I'm giving a few recommendations based on your posted code:

1. You're using `sTimeFormat`, which must be at least a `static` variable, and is probably `final` as well (and usually should be, in this context).  However, you aren't following naming conventions -it should probably be named `TIMESTAMP_FORMATTER` (if the only thing you do is get an actual date, use `TIMESTAMP_PARSER`).  Also, although you're not likely to be using multiple threads on an android device, please be aware `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` are **NOT** threadsafe - the standard practice is to contruct a copy for each use.
2. You're manually formatting the timestamp itself, before attempting to parse it.  There's no point - you should be using the existing data (eiither from the xml directly, or the rendered html), and supplying a custom formatting string.
3. You're setting two parts of the dates, year and timezone.  At minimum, that should be moved outside of the actual parse piece.  You should probably write a `setToCanonicalDate` method or something that takes the output from your parsing and sets it to the valid year and timezone.  And how far are you distributing that app?  I live in the Pacific Timezone - your default won't do me any good.

Answer (score -2):

This is how you can work with time and long:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dp.getDayOfMonth());
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, dp.getMonth());;
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, dp.getYear());

long l = c.getTime().getTime();
```

Comment: -1 - While true, this doesn't appear to be relevant here.  Additionally, if `dp` is a date, you're using deprecated (or should be) methods.